# Can not get more then 100% CPU usage for docker container

Tags: docker

I am trying to get my container to run on multiple CPU's.
To achieve this on Windows, I changed .wslconfig to have:

```
[wsl2]
memory= 8GB
processors=4
```

Using docker stats, I can see the available RAM reduced from 12.xx to 7.764, so I can see this file has changed the behaviour.

However, if I run my container with the following command:

```
docker run -d --cpus="4" "CONTAINERNAME"
```

and then I check the stats using docker stats, I still see the container using 100% CPU% at maximum. Since the contianer has more cpu's available, I was expecting this to now be able to go above the 100%.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: is the process running inside the container able to use more than one cpu?

Comment: if I run it on my own pc (not in container), it uses 30-40 % cpu, and my pc has 8 cpus. So I would think it can?